# if globlal variabales can be read from local scope then why cant i get global variable printed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I do not know why I am seeing an `UnboundLocalError`:

```
def spam():
        print(eggs)
        eggs = 'spam local'
eggs = 'global'
spam()
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you rebind `eggs` to the local scope with `eggs = 'spam local'` is the trigger for this.

Python thinks `eggs` will be in the local scope due to that assignment, when it looks `eggs` up during the call to `print` it will complain that it is trying to reference a variable (`eggs`) before the assignment is performed (line after the print).

In general, I haven't seen anything that requires what you're trying to do, either way, you can either get it to work by using `global` to indicate to Python that you'll be altering a name in the global scope:

```
def spam():
    global eggs
    print(eggs)
    eggs = 'spam local'
```

or, pass the value as an argument, this doesn't alter the value globally but makes it available locally to remedy the reference failing to be found during the first print call:

```
def spam(eggs=eggs):
    print(eggs)
    eggs = 'spam local'
```

These two approaches have different semantics, of course:

- The first is essentially a hint which tells Python you'll be referencing/altering a variable located in the global scope, so it *knows* how to load/store it.
- The second makes `eggs` available in the local scope by using it as a parameter, the global value for `eggs` is attached as its default value. The look-up for `eggs` in `print` now works while `eggs = 'spam local'` is going to alter the `eggs` located in the local scope.

You can choose depending on what you're trying to experiment with.